# django MultiValueDictKeyError while requesting get object

Tags: django, forms, request

I have made a form to filter `ListView`

```
class SingleNewsView(ListView):
    model = News
    form_class = SearchForm
    template_name = "single_news.html"

    def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):
        self.pk = pk

        pub_from = request.GET['pub_date_from']
        pub_to = request.GET['pub_date_to']
        
        return super(SingleNewsView,self).get(request,pk, **kwargs)
```

My form fields are `pub_date_from` and `pub_date_to`. When I run the site it says:
`MultiValueDictKeyError`  .

I don't know what's going on. When I remove the two line of getting `pub_from` and `pub_to` the site works fine. I want these two values to filter the queryset.

Comment: You are submitting form with `GET` method? You may want to try with `request.POST`.

Comment: yeah I m submitting with GET. Post didnt worked. After removing pub_date_from once and running the site and the again putting it works. But starting from begining dont work. :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On first request there is no form data submitted so `request.GET` would not have any data. So doing `request.GET['pub_date_from']` will fail. You shall use `.get()` method

```
pub_from = request.GET.get('pub_date_from')
pub_to = request.GET.get('pub_date_to')
```

If these keys are not in the dict, will return `None`. So handle the such cases appropriately in your code.

Also, if you want to filter objects for `ListView` add `get_queryset()` method to return filtered queryset as explained here [Dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)