# Recover GET parameter from PasswordResetConfirmView

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I'm trying to recover a `GET` parameter from the Django template view `django.contrib.auth.PasswordResetConfirmView`.
Basically when a user click on his password reset link (like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/commons/reset/MQ/4t8-210d1909d621e8b4c68e/?origin_page=/mypage/`) I want to be able to retrieve the `origin_page=/mypage/` argument. So far my `url.py` looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'commons'
urlpatterns = [
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

And my `views.py` like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

class PasswordResetConfirmView(auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = 'commons/password_reset_confirm.html'
    success_url = '/commons/reset/done/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_context = {
            'origin_page': request.GET.get('origin_page')
        }
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see I'm trying to get my `origin_page` with `'origin_page': request.GET.get('origin_page')` but it doesn't work, I get a `None` value. I even used the debugger to inspect every objects from the class/method but none of them seems to contains my `origin_page` variable.
Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django MultiValueDictKeyError while requesting get object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322953/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-while-requesting-get-object)

Comment: Not exactly the same, I modified my code accordingly

Comment: Also, be careful about using untrusted `origin_page` from the user. If you look at the Django admin app, it checks the `next` value before redirecting.

Comment: @Alasdair Sorry I edited my post, I forgot to change that. Indeed I get a `None` value instead of a key error. So I shouldn't put a `origin_page` parameter in my password reset url? Why would be the best way to do it then? I need to know from what webpage the user sent his password reset.

Comment: If you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/commons/reset/MQ/4t8-210d1909d621e8b4c68e/?origin_page=/mypage/` then `request.GET.get('origin_page')` should be `'/mypage/'`. It's hard to debug further because the code should work.

Comment: You can get the url from `request.GET`, but you should check it first. Look, for example, at [what the Django auth app does](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L72).

Comment: I get a `MultiValueDictKeyError` with `request.GET['origin_page']`

Comment: As we’ve already said, you should use `get()` to avoid the `KeyError`. If `get()` returns `None`, that means you’ve gone to a url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/commons/reset/MQ/4t8-210d1909d621e8b4c‌​68e/` that doesn’t have `origin_url` in the querystring.

Comment: And what I'm trying to say is that neither `request.GET['origin_page']` nor `request.GET.get('origin_page')` have my `origin_page` argument and I'm 100% sure I use this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/commons/reset/MQ/4t8-210d1909d621e8b4c68e/?origin_page=/mysite/`. Somehow it seems the `django.contrib.auth.PasswordResetConfirmView` removes it or forbid me to access it.

Comment: Django views can’t forbid access to `request.GET`. There’s nothing in the question that explains why `request.GET.get()` wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

The `PasswordResetConfirmView` does an internal redirect which removes the token from the URL. Because of this, any query params you pass with the email also get removed. The line of code that does this is in the `dispatch` function of `PasswordResetConfirmView` which replaces the path with a constant:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L280

```
redirect_url = self.request.path.replace(token, self.reset_url_token)
```

So you have the right idea that you need to subclass the `PasswordResetConfirmView` but I believe you need to alter the `dispatch` function, where the function is mostly the same, except add the original query param back to the `redirect_url`:

```
# tack on whatever query params came with the email link
redirect_url = f'{redirect_url}?{self.request.GET.urlencode()}'
```